# addEventListener is being triggered twice

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener that listens for hotkeys that's being triggered twice. I'm pretty sure I know the reason why but not how to fix it.

So I have a program that displays several questions, and for each question I use a new event listener attached to the document (To avoid focus issues). I think the next question is being displayed, and a new event listener is being created while the hot key is still pressed, causing the program to select the answer for two questions instead of one.

Is there someway to yield until the key is no longer pressed (Assuming that's the issue)? Here's my code.

```
function showQuestion() {
    function checkKeySelectAnswer(keypress) {
        let key_code = keypress.keyCode
        //document.removeEventListener('keydown', checkKeySelectAnswer)
        console.log('showQuestion Checking key press, key_code is ', key_code)
        if (key_code === 37) {
            console.log('showQuestion Left arrow pressed')
            console.log('showQuestion Result is ', question_object['answers']['No'])
            selectAnswer('No', question_object['answers']['No'])
        } else if (key_code === 39) {
            console.log('showQuestion Right arrow pressed')
            console.log('showQuestion Result is ', question_object['answers']['Yes'])
            selectAnswer('Yes', question_object['answers']['Yes'])
        }
    }
    let question_object
    if (checkSubQuestion(current_index)) {
        question_object = user_dict['questions'][section][category][current_index]['sub_questions'][current_sub_index]
        console.log('showQuestion More sub questions found, question_object is ', question_object)
    } else {
        question_object = user_dict['questions'][section][category][current_index]
        console.log('showQuestion More questions found, question_object is ', question_object)
    }
    removeAnswers()
    questionElement.innerText = question_object['question']
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(question_object['answers'])) {
        let answer = key
        let result = value
        const button = document.createElement('button')
        button.innerText = answer
        if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
            if (answer === 'No') {
                button.classList.add('no-btn')
            } else if (answer === 'Yes') {
                button.classList.add('yes-btn')
            }
        }
        button.classList.add('btn')
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            selectAnswer(answer, result)
        })
        answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    }
    document.addEventListener('keydown', checkKeySelectAnswer, { once: true})
}
```

Comment: Have you tried destroying old event listeners when you attach new ones?

Comment: Just replace keydown to keyup

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it fixed some of the problems, but I'm still having issues with a specific case that I can't easily reproduce in an example here. Keyup definitely improved it though so thanks. @P.B.UDAY I did destroy old event listeners originally, but instead found the "once" option which ensures the event can only be triggered one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your listeners outside of your function loop as they're getting recreated each time the function runs. The keydown listener you should just remove each time the function gets called and let it create itself at the end. I put the button-creation modifications below.

```
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-answer')) selectAnswer(e.target.innerText, e.target.dataset.result)
})

function showQuestion() {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', checkKeySelectAnswer)
    function checkKeySelectAnswer(keypress) {
    .... 
        button.innerText = answer
        button.setAttribute('data-result', result);
        button.classList.add('btn btn-answer')
```

Comment: Thanks, I initially tried using keyup as mentioned in the other solution, but I was still having issues so I tried your solution along with a global wait_for_input bool and it works perfectly. Thanks so much.